# Ping federate as IDp, consuming the SAML 2.0 response in ASP .net web forms

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, pingfederate

What is the best open source or paid library to make ASP .net web forms application as relying party, sign in a user, when Ping Federate as Idp.

PingFederate Integration Kit
https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/NETIK/.NET+Integration+Kit

One Login
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet

Kentor.AuthServices
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices

Do all these solutions use open token protocol ?

Thanks
ameet

Comment: Are you the SP? Do you have a spec-compliant SP implementation? Will the application you speak of be running on the IdP's site and entirely under their control, or no? The .net integration kit uses OpenToken, OneLogin and Kentor use SAML.

Comment: Since I asked this question, I have implemented, the SP part in ASP .Net Using ComponentSpace, which is third party paid library. Works pretty well and has test Idp settings also to test your SP implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Calling one library *the best* is not that straightforward as it's highly circumstantial.

If you're the Ping Identity customer yourself, the Integration Kit would make sense, as it's supported by Ping, making life easier if something goes wrong. This limits you to an integration with PingFederate, but doesn't mean a SAML 2.0 connection couldn't be set up via PingFederate.

If the application might be offered to other customers who don't run PingFederate, using one of the SAML 2.0 libraries might make more sense, as it would be possible to connect anyone who has a SAML 2.0-supporting solution in place.

I don't know how support with the OneLogin Toolkit works, but Kentor is Open-Source, which needs to be considered prior making the choice.

OpenToken is not a standard, and the PingFederate implementation *might* not work with 3rd-party or Open-Source libraries.

Comment: Thanks Mehmet. We are not Ping Identity customer, but our client is whose users need to be authenticated. I believe the Ping Identity .net integration kit should be free to use for such cases. Will Ping's .net integration kit only work with Ping ?

Comment: The .NET Integration Kit is for PingFederate, therefore will work with PingFederate. I personally favor Open Standards (e.g. SAML 2.0) as it's more future-proof and less vendor-dependent.